# Adding and retrieving sorted counts in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a case where I need to record a user action in Cassandra, then later retrieve a sorted list of users with the highest number of that action in an arbitrary time period.

Can anyone suggest a way to store and retrieve this data in a pre-aggregated method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of Cassandra I would recommend using [stream-summary](http://boundary.com/blog/2013/05/14/approximate-heavy-hitters-the-spacesaving-algorithm/) or count min sketch you would be able to solve this with much less space and have immediate results.  Just update and periodically serialize and persist it (assuming you don't need guaranteed accuracy)

In Cassandra you can keep a row per period of time like by hours and have a counter per user in that row, incrementing them on use.  Then use a batch job to run through them and find the heavy hitters.  You would be constrained to having the minimal queryable time be 1 hour and it wont be particularly cheap or fast to compute but it would work.

Generally it would be good treating these as a log of operation, every time there is an event store it and have batch jobs do analytics against it with hadoop or custom.  If need it realtime id recommend the above approach of keeping stream summaries in memory.